# checking attribute to another element on unchecked radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im pretty stuck on it, I cant find a way to make the image to be changed when the user is unchecking a radio button (means, the user checked another radio)

CODE:

```
handleCheckbox = e => {

    let target = e.target;
    let targetName = !target.type ? e.target.getAttribute('name') : e.target.getAttribute('value')

        if (targetName == 'bstFbBtn' ) {
            if ( target.checked) {
                target.nextSibling.src = fbColorSVG

            } 
            else {
                target.nextSibling.src = fbGreySVG
            }                
        }
    }

<label>
     <input type="radio" onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}  style={Style.checkBox} value="bstFbBtn" name="bestReach" />
     <img src={fbGreySVG} name="bstFbBtn" style={Style.icon}/>                            
</label>
```

the issue with that code is that it wont capture the time when the element in unchecked ( because the even is passed already ) and when I get back to it the image is the same because , well , it's checked again. I know my logic is wrong here. There is any way to make it right?

Comment: Never mutate DOM elements or change their attributes manually. React should do that for you during rendering. You only describe **how your DOM should look like given the current state** and not how it should change when the user clicks something (this would be jQuery style). You have to store the current selection in component state and render accordingly. When the user changes the selection only update that state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state for setting the src for image according to radio-button click

```
 handleCheckbox = e => {
        let target = e.target;
        let targetName = !target.type ? e.target.getAttribute('name') : e.target.getAttribute('value')
            if (targetName == 'bstFbBtn' ) {
                if ( target.checked) {
                    this.setState({src:fbColorSVG})
                } 
                else {
                    this.setState({src:fbGreySVG})
                }                
            }
        }
```

Then in render method the source can be given as

```
render() {
    <label>
         <input type="radio" onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}  style={Style.checkBox} value="bstFbBtn" name="bestReach" />
         <img src={this.state.src} name="bstFbBtn" style={Style.icon}/>                            
    </label>
}
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working. It has the same issue, yes the `setState` force the state to update but it will be invoked only when the target is checked , therefore it will only update the state when the target is checked so there will always be the same image

Answer (score 0):

ok So I managed to find a solutions and if someone has this issue you can do this:

```
this.stete = {
  ...
  checked: {
    ...
    fb:false,
    ...
  }
  ...
}

handleCheckbox = e => {

    let target = e.target;
    let targetName = !target.type ? e.target.getAttribute('name') : e.target.getAttribute('value') 


    if (targetName == 'bstFbBtn' ) {
        let { checked } = this.state;
        checked.fb = true;
        this.setState({checked}, () => {
            let { checked } = this.state;
            for (let key in checked) {
                if (key != 'fb') {
                    checked[key] = false;
                }
            }
            console.log(checked)
            this.setState({checked:checked})
        })
    }
}
<label>
     <input type="radio" onChange={e => this.handleInputChange(e)}  style={Style.checkBox} value="bstFbBtn" name="bestReach" />
 {
     this.state.checked.fb ?  
     <img src={fbColorSVG} name="bstFbBtn" style={Style.icon}/> :
     <img src={fbGreySVG} name="bstFbBtn" style={Style.icon}/> 
 }

</label>
```